# Как сделать прыгающую букву при наведении на неё css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

На этом [сайте](https://jacekjeznach.com/about) есть текст **"My, myself & I"**.

Как сделать свой текст таким же анимированным как на этом сайте?

Чтобы буквы также подпрыгивали при наведении на них?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стили взял прям из примера, а на js просто добавлять и удалять класс при наведение.
Вот пример:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.blast').forEach(el => {

  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    el.classList.add('rubberBand', 'animated');
  })
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    el.classList.remove('rubberBand', 'animated');
  })

})
```

```css
.rubberBand {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}

.blast {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
    }

    30% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
        transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1)
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
        transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1)
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
        transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1)
    }

    65% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
        transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1)
    }

    75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
        transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1)
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="blast">М</span>
<span class="blast">О</span>
<span class="blast">Л</span>
<span class="blast">О</span>
<span class="blast">Д</span>
<span class="blast">Е</span>
<span class="blast">Ц</span>
```

**P.S:** @NDMX правильно заметил - мой пример не совсем верно отрабатывал как в примере, спасибо.

Правильный вариант из примера:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.blast').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    el.classList.add('rubberBand', 'animated');
    setTimeout(() => {
      el.classList.remove('rubberBand', 'animated')
    }, 1000)
  })
})
```

```css
@keyframes rubberBand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1)
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1)
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
  }
}

.rubberBand {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}

.blast {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out
}
```

```html
<span class="blast">М</span>
<span class="blast">О</span>
<span class="blast">Л</span>
<span class="blast">О</span>
<span class="blast">Д</span>
<span class="blast">Е</span>
<span class="blast">Ц</span>
```

Comment: Не совсем так работает, как в оригинальном примере.  Думаю нужно добавить setTimeout в событии mouseleave, чтобы анимация проигрывала полностью, а не заканчивалась, когда указатель уходит с элемента.

Comment: @NDMX да, точно. У меня сразу удаляется если убрать а там проигрывает анимация. Спасибо - сейчас подправлю

Comment: Не могу понять,я скопировал всё также,как у вас и вставил в html css и js,но у меня по какой-то причине не работает анимация

Comment: @Zesshi точно все верно скопировали? css и js верно подключены? Ошибки есть в консоли?

Comment: Я нашёл ошибку,почему-то если я добавляю через <script> </script> в самом html всё работает,а когда подключаю непосредственно js через отдельный файлл ничего не работает

Comment: Хотя странно,так как вроде всё правильно подключено 
Подключение делал в head  <script src="main.js"></script>
И файл находится в одной и той же папке

Comment: Но всё равно спасибо вам большое за код

Comment: @Zesshi пожалуйста

Comment: А не могли бы подсказать ещё кое что? Как их сделать,чтобы они некоторые буквы были ближе друг другу,а то они все с большим пробелом между друг другом

Comment: @Zesshi может свойство letter-spacing попробуете?

Comment: @Zesshi , font-size: 0 для родительского блока решит проблему. И подключайте js не в head, а перед закрывающимся тегом </body>.

Comment: @NDMX спасибо большое,после того,как вставил скрипт в конец body всё получилось